# Algunos ejemplos de subjuntivo sin "que"

Tags: gramática, subjuntivo, modismos

Entiendo cuándo usar el subjuntivo con frases como "espero que *verbo subjuntivo*…" y muchas frases similares.

Sin embargo, estoy confuso con qué otras palabras y combinaciones lo utilizan.

Por ejemplo frases sin construcciones como:

```
Buscan un hombre que hable inglés para el trabajo.
```

vs:

```
Conozco un hombre que habla inglés.
```

Comment: Así como está redactada, la pregunta es un poco demasiado genérica. Intenta indicar algún ejemplo que no entiendas para poder ayudarte mejor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El subjuntivo posee varias formas de convocarse cuando no se dispone de un *que* o un *de que.*

> *Cuando **tengas** hijos, te darás cuenta.*
>   *Ojalá **puedas** ir.*
>   ***Fuese*** ese el caso o no, tendremos que ceder.
>   *Si tan solo **hablaras** más despacio.*
>   *Jamás **vayas** a fallar.*

Esto también incluye las oraciones de subjuntivo sobre los condicionales:

> *Si **pasase** esto...*
>   ***Hubiera*** sabido...

Para los imperativos en negativo, siempre se convoca el subjuntivo:

> *No lo **hagas**.*
>   *No **tomes** decisiones apresuradas.*

Así sucesivamente, hay infinidades de ejemplos para convocar el modo subjuntivo sin usar el *que* o *de que.*

Answer (score 2):

No estoy seguro de que sea lo que quieres saber, pero, según la *Nueva gramática de la lengua española*, el *que* puede omitirse en ciertas oraciones sustantivas subordinadas:

> Admiten omisión de *que* con subordinadas en subjuntivo
>
> Los verbos de petición, mandato y otras formas de influencia:
>
> *Le solicitaron cumpliese la promesa dada.*
>
> *El toro era mando y el público pidió fuese devuelto al corral.*
>
> *La ley ordena sean castigados con dos años de prisión.*
>
> El verbo *agradecer* cuando introduce peticiones cuyo cumplimiento se
>   agradece por anticipado:
>
> *Mucho le agradecería me comunicara si acepta las condiciones del
>   contrato.*
>
> Algunos verbos de voluntad, en particular los que ponen de manifiesto
>   la actitud favorable del sujeto en relación con lo que ha de suceder:
>
> *Te deseo seas muy feliz en tu matrimonio.*
>
> *Te deseo tengas suerte en la vida.*
>
> Algunas subordinadas de sujeto:
>
> *Es necesario tenga presente que...*
>
> *Es posible exista petróleo en esta región.*

Para más detalles, puedes consultar en [este extracto de la NGLE](http://hispanoteca.eu/gram%C3%A1ticas/Gram%C3%A1tica%20espa%C3%B1ola/Conjunci%C3%B3n%20que%20-%20omisi%C3%B3n.htm), o en el [sitio oficial de la RAE](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/buscar.cgi) (pon "43.3" en el buscador).

Answer (score 0):

Según entiendo yo el subjuntivo no habla necesariamente de una realidad asegurada.

- "*Busco a un hombre que **hable** inglés*" = (ese hombre en principio no existe, es un deseo tuyo. Puede ser cualquiera que tenga esa capacidad pero desconoces quien será.
- "*Busco a un hombre que habla inglés*"
  Expresa un hecho. No un deseo, ese hombre existe y lo has perdido. (Lo.que deseas es encontrarlo) Por ejemplo: tu amigo Británico vino de vacaciones y no lo encuentras. No quieres a cualquiera que hable inglés, sino a tu amigo.
- Un ejemplo más claro es. *Que tengas un buen día*. (Deseo) //
  *Tienes un buen día*. (Realidad)

Comment: Bienvenido/a a [Spanish.se]. Te recomiendo visitar las secciones de [tour] y [help] para entender un poco mejor la filosofía de este sitio. Échale también un vistazo a otras preguntas y respuestas. Procura responder _realmente_ a la pregunta y recuerda que el formato adecuado puede servir para hacer tu respuesta más fácil de leer y entender. No dudes en pedir ayuda si lo necesitas. Bienvenida de nuevo. ¡Esperamos seguir viendo contribuciones tuyas en el futuro! La pregunta es sobre subjunctivo _sin_ que.